# print's order of execution

Tags: java, string, printing

This program gives output -

```
A 1 2
```

Shouldn't it give output -

```
1 A 2
```

since first a.i should print 1 and then a.getI() executes and should print A 2

```
public class A1{

     int i=1;

     public int getI(){
          System.out.print("A ");
          return i+1;
     }

     public static void main(String args[]){
          A1 a=new A1();
          System.out.print(a.i+" "+a.getI());
     }
}
```

Comment: Nope. a.getI() this will be called first

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this expression:

```
a.i+" "+a.getI()
```

The call to `a.getI()` gets evaluated first, and afterwards the string is formed by concatenating `a.i` plus `a.getI()`

Answer (score 9):

The first thing the JVM does is constructing the String. So it starts here:

```
a.i + " "
```

This is first done. Now, we have `"1 "`. Next it handles this:

```
"1 " + a.getI()
```

To stitch the two parts, the method will be executed to know what to stitch together.
So, now enter the metod:

```
System.out.print("A ");
return i+1;
```

The first print statement is executed. `"A "` is printed to the console (**1**). Now the method returns `i + 1`, which is `2`.
This means we have this:

```
"1 " + "2"
```

which is `"1 2"`. At this point the string building is done, so it is passed to `println()`.
Now `"1 2"` is printed to the console.(**2**)

As you can see, first was (**1**) executed and then (**2**). So, in the console this results in:

```
A 1 2
```